# Object values undefined on IE

Tags: javascript, json, internet-explorer

I've got this flow on an enterprise application:

1. on every service page there is a "search box". When user starts to type something in it a call to a Struts 2 action in fired (via JQuery autocompleter)
2. on action call, Hibernate looks for *hints* on user search on a MySql database
3. when hints are found a JSON response is given. Something like:

   ```
   ...
   "map": {
         "id": "1234",
         "title": "Title 1",
         "permalink": "title-1",
         "class": "contentClassA",
         "contentType": "Content type ..."
       },
   ...
   ```
4. back on frontend JSP, some Javascript creates a list ov `<div>`, each of them containg the data of a `map` object.

Steps 1-4 is working on Firefox up to version 11 and Internet Explorer to version 9. Then via Javascript I try to build a `self.location` redirect to reload the page discriminating on the `class` value. And here is the problem. The `obj` variable contains a single JSON `map` as stated above, and I do:

```
    var classType; 
    if(obj['class'] != undefined) {
        classType = obj['class'];
    } else {
        //classType = obj.map.class;
        //classType = obj['map'].class;
        //classType = obj.class;
        // ...
        classType = obj.map['class'];
    }
```

Everything is ok on FF, but IE (ver. 7-8-9) falls into the *else* and the `classType` variable returned is undefined no matter what I try.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is with propertyName `"class"`, which is a reserved keyword in js. Check below link.

http://javascript.about.com/library/blreserved.htm

Even I faced similar issue with IE, I simply renamed the key `class` to `className`

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what purpose you have with this logic. But, if you want to check if `obj.map` has a `class` key, use `hasOwnProperty`:

```
if (obj.map.hasOwnProperty('class')) {
    // do something with obj.map['class']
}
```

If you don’t know if `map` is present in `obj` you can check for that too:

```
if ('map' in obj && obj.map.hasOwnProperty('class')) {
    //
}
```

There are many ways to check if properties exists in an object, all depending on how much control you have of the data and what cases you need to account for.

Comment: Thanks, but I already know that the key is present and has a value, because in FF, Chrome and Safari it works